# Hypothesis Test: Difference in Rates with Null Values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am trying to test whether a difference in rates is significant, where either the numerator and the denominator can be 0. What is the most appropriate test to use?

For a specific (imaginary) example, I have a sample of towns across two states. Within each state, I have the number of fires (x) per town, and the total number of fire brigades in the town, y. The question of interest is whether the rate of fires, per fire brigade, differs across states.

Setting aside a model-based approach, what is the best test to use here? I don't believe I can use a standard t-test of scaled observations, since the rate (x/y) is undefined for towns without fire stations. I also don't think it's appropriate to use a standard difference in proportions test (Chi-squared, etc) because the data doesn't seem to fit the standard success/attempts model. However, I'm a novice. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your observations in the second paragraph bring you to a fundamental point: what would it mean to test a quantity that is undefined in the population?  Until you can clarify this point it would seem impossible to justify any kind of test.

Comment: Nevertheless, fires without fire stations do occur. So although it's undefined in terms of a rate, it should still affect the quantity of interest, which is sum(x)/sum(y) for each state, no?

Comment: Nobody is denying reality. Our concern lies in how you are representing it and what you want to learn about it so that you get good information from your data. A close reading of the question suggests the rate *is* defined for each state, presuming each has at least one brigade. There are various good ways to estimate that rate from your data. They require us to know how the towns were sampled: presumably at random, but with what probabilities? Are probabilities equal for each town, proportional to population, to numbers of buildings, to numbers of fires, or what?

Comment: Right: but please tell us about the probability of sampling each town.  Does every town--no matter what its population--have an equal chance of being in your sample?  For instance, if you were studying Massachusetts, would Boston (population 610K, with many fire brigades) have the same chance of being included as Gosnold (population 75, [one fire station](http://www.boston.com/news/special/fires/departments/gosnold.html))?

Comment: All towns have an equal probability of being in the sample; assume balance in terms of background characteristics (the real example does not have a confounder similar to population).